# "geladen" in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

This sentence is from a [*Spiegel* article](http://www.spiegel.de/sport/sonst/olympia-2016-in-rio-gesamtes-russisches-team-muss-um-teilnahme-zittern-a-1098449.html). The context is discussions about the Olympics and banning the Russian team for doping.  The sentence in question is the first sentence under the third paragraph (under the “Wann geht es weiter?” headline):

> Für den 21. Juni hat IOC-Präsident Thomas Bach zum so genannten Olympic Summit nach Lausanne geladen.

I thought at first that *geladen* in this sentence meant *invited,* but given that *to invite* requires a direct object in this context and that there is none, I was wondering if there was another definition of *geladen* that I may be missing (most of the other definitions of *geladen* are *charged* or *loaded,* which doesn’t make sense in this context).

Comment: Just because "to invite" might require a direct object (which I do not think is true, by the way) does not mean that "laden" does so, too. Not even getting into the discussion that there are no direct objects in German.

Comment: I would disagree about "to invite" not requiring a direct object. But I did not know about german not having direct objects. Is this because they would be called "accusative objects"?

Comment: I am pretty sure "to invite" can be used without a direct object expressing the action of "giving invitation" - Just like in German. With regards to usage of the term "direct object": Just search here for that term, there are answers around.

Comment: I'd just like to add that "einladen" doesn't require a direct object either and could be used in the sentence above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [two verbs *laden*](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=laden) with different etymologies. The one you are looking for is the second; in the dictionary panel click on the small *laden²* to open its entry.

In short, *laden* in this case is a higher-register variant of *einladen*. It does not require an accusative object but can go without one. If there is no object, it is usually assumed that *everybody* or *everybody whose appearance makes sense* is the recipient of the invitation.

Comment: Der letzte Satz ist doch eine wüste Spekulation. Es wird (in dem Satz) einfach nicht gesagt wer geladen ist - was das bedeutet mag aus dem Kontext folgern. Vielleicht ist es auch unbekannt oder unerheblich.

Answer (score 3):

While *laden* can actually be a more literate form of *einladen* (it has also the different meaning, where it is not just an invitation but a formal request to appear, with non-compliance having severe consequences; typically issued by police or a court) none of the two **strictly** requires an object, as in

> Die Gemeinde hat zum Sommerfest (ein-) geladen